# I have 2 buttons that can be active, how to make the browser remember which one has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have 2 buttons in my navbar for language( fr/en ) and I'm adding an active class to the one that is clicked. But when the user navigates away from the page the 2 buttons go back to being inactive.

How do I make the browser remember what button has been clicked and automatically add the active class to it on all pages? I have looked into localStorage but I don't get how to make it work!

```
//code to add the active class

$('.language').each(function(){
   var self = $(this)
   $(this).click(function(){
      $('.language').removeClass('active')
      self.addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Comment: It seems like you're using jQuery - I'd suggest getting the jQuery cookie plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).  You can save their preference in a cookie, then pull the information on every page load

Comment: `localStorage` is one option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. Alternatively, you could modify the URL of the page to include the language.

Comment: You may get some idea follow the answer in this post.
<http://stackoverflow.com/a/32015738/3183458>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned on of the ways to achieve this is using the localStorage.

Here is an example:

```js
$('.language').each(function(){
   var self = $(this)
   $(this).click(function(){
     window.localStorage.setItem('active-language', $(this).text());
      $('.language').removeClass('active')
      self.addClass('active');
   });
});
if (window.localStorage.getItem('active-language')) {
  $('.language').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == window.localStorage.getItem('active-language')) {
      $(this).click();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.language.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="language">en</span> <span class="language">fe</span>
```

> snippets in stackoverflow do not allow the usage of localStorage, so here is a jsfiddle working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ogwktf08/